# Tabing out of parentheses in snippets only under certain circumstances

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have the following snippet

```
"Inline Math":{
  "prefix": "mk",
  "body": "$ $1 $ $2"
}
```

and I would like to do the following:
"**mk**"+ "**tab**"+"**f**"+"("+"**x**" +"**tab**" "**+**"+"**1**" +"tab" and get the following as output

```
$f(x)+1$ |
```

where | denotes my cursor. When I write this now I get

```
$f(x)$ +1|
```

I tried using the TabOut extension but it seems like the priority for "**Tab**" is given to the snippet , rather than the brackets in the snippet. Is it possible that I can add this feature for when I am in the snippet? **Moreover**, is it possible to add it in such a way that it doesn't break with snippets of the form

```
"Worrying case":{
  "prefix": "wory",
  "body": "some random code ($1) some random words $2"
}
```

(that is, snippets that include a placeholder in a parentheses)? Maybe such a way that it works for parentheses I have manually typed in?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you have `$ $2` when you want the `$` after `$2`

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for the comment. I have edited my question to be clear. Is this more understandable?

Comment: I used `"body": "$$1 $2$"` and got the result you want, I have no problems with the worry snippet

Comment: Hi @rioV8 thank you for the comment. I think my issue with this is that this doesn't generalize well in most situations I use it in. I use "mk" for inline math mode so in this case I can leave it like this, but for example, what happens if I want to incomperate this to other commands involving pmatrix, fractions and so on? If I haven't explained myself well please let me know.

Comment: it looks like latex and that I don't use a lot, only if I need some stuff in MathJax because Berners Lee did not had the courage to put Latex Math in the HTML standard although he was working at Cern and I think they do a lot of math, or he did not know how to render Latex Math in his first Mozaik Web browser